# Detect intrusion with Apache log (IDS)

Tags: apache2

I have an apache log. is there ane IDS (Intrusion Detecting System) to detect Intrusions in my server ?
***I just have an apache log***

Answer (score 2):

There is a application named as [Apache-scalp](http://code.google.com/p/apache-scalp/). It is a Apache log analyzer .

> Scalp! is a log analyzer for the Apache web server that aims to look
>   for security problems. The main idea is to look through huge log files
>   and extract the possible attacks that have been sent through HTTP/GET
>   (By default, Apache does not log the HTTP/POST variable).

You can download it from : http://code.google.com/p/apache-scalp/downloads/detail?name=scalp-0.4.py

Usage Example:

```
./scalp-0.4.py -l /var/log/httpd_log -f ./default_filter.xml -o ./scalp-output --html
```

Features:

Scalp has a couple of options that may be useful in order to save time when scalping a huge log file or in order to perform a full examination; the default options are almost okay for log files of hundreds of MB.

Current options:

- exhaustive: Won't stop at the first pattern matched, but will test all the patterns
- tough: Will decode a part of potential attacks (this is done to use better the regexp from PHP-IDS in order to decrease the false-negative rate)
- period: Specify a time-frame to look at, all the rest will be ignored
- sample: Does a random sampling of the log lines in order to look at a certain percentage, this is useful when the user doesn't want to do a full scan of all the log, but just ping it to see if there is some problem.
- attack: Specify what classes of vulnerabilities the tool will look at (eg, look only for XSS, SQL Injection, etc.)